# bash indirect reference by reference

Tags: bash, variables

A lot of similar questions, but hadn't found one for using a variable in the name this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 should be 'dev' or 'stg'

dev_path="/path/to/123"
stg_path="/path/to/xyz"

# Use $1 as input to determine which path variable to 'execute'
${!\$1'/morepath'}
```

Using $1, I want to be able to reference either $dev_path or $stg_path ($1 == 'dev' or $1 == 'stg') and be able to reference the value of $1_path which would be '/path/to/123' or '/path/to/xyz'

so the result would either be:

```
'/path/to/123/morepath' or '/path/to/xyz/morepath'
```

based upon $1 being 'dev' or 'stg'.

I've tried various iterations of using ! and \$ in various places from other posts, but no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that would be unsafe. If `$1` gets a value that's not dev or stg it would cause syntax error and other unexpected things may happen. Even with `eval` it wouldn't be a good idea unless you add a conditional filter. You could use a `case` statement:

```
case "$1" in
dev)
    "$dev_path"/bin/execute
    ;;
std)
    "$std_path"/bin/execute
    ;;
*)
    echo "Invalid argument: $1"
    ;;
esac
```

Or make sure it's valid and use eval:

```
[[ $1 == dev || $1 == std ]] && eval "\"\${${1}_path}/bin/execute\""
```

Using `if ... elif ...` could be valid too but the `case` method is simpler.

As for `variable indirection` you would need to store `"${1}_path"` to another variable first which is unnecessary.

You could also use `dev|std) eval ... ;;` in the `case` statement at your preference.

Answer (score 6):

See the Bash manual section on [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> If the first character of *parameter* is an exclamation point (!), a level of variable indirection is introduced. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of *parameter* as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of *parameter* itself. This is known as `indirect expansion`. The exceptions to this are the expansions of `${!prefix
>   }` and `${!name[@]}` described below. The exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to introduce indirection.
>
> [...]

Since you also want to modify the name (by suffixing `_path`) before expanding again, you need to go through another variable:

```
# $1 should be 'dev' or 'stg'
dev_path="/path/to/dev"
stg_path="/path/to/stg"

path=${1}_path   # path is now either 'dev_path' or 'stg_path'

# Run either /path/to/dev or /path/to/stg
${!path}/bin/execute
```

Of course, if both of the `dev` and `stg` programs are in the same directory, then there's no need for all this, you can just directly expand `$1`:

```
/path/to/$1/bin/execute
```

Comment: $1 (e.g. dev/stg) shouldn't be involved except for the variable name (not value) edited question to help clarify

Answer (score 0):

Why the need for a "variable, variable"? Why not

```
MYPATH="/path/to/$1"
$MYPATH/bin/execute
```

Comment: $1 (e.g. dev/stg) shouldn't be involved except for the variable name (not value) edited question to help clarify